# Reading rows from a table in BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to use BeautifulSoup for the first time to read a table.

```
print table_body
```

works but

```
rows = table_body.find_all('tr')
```

gives

```
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable.
```

The result of the `print table_body` is:

```
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>1</td>
<td><input type="checkbox" checked="checked" value="1098371296_GG14" class="tick_select" name="tick_select" id="tick_1098371296_GG14" /></td>
<td><a href="application.jsp?number=1322801&amp;cycle=16/17&amp;route=routecode&amp;seq=0">1098371296</a></td>
<td>GG14</td>
<td>Joe</td>
<td>Doe</td>
<td>US</td>
<td>15/16</td>
<td>15/01/15</td>
<td></td>
<td>05/05/15</td>
<td></td>
<td>R</td>
<td> <abbr title="Withdrawn">Cw</abbr> <abbr title="MS">Mt</abbr> <abbr title="UF elsewhere">Ue</abbr></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
[...]
```

What am I doing wrong?

I am using BeautifulSoup version 3.2.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because `findAll` is renamed `find_all` in more recent versions of BeautifulSoup, so write `table_body.findAll('tr')`  instead.

Answer (score 2):

To add and to change the focus of the @larsr's answer:

You *should not be using BeautifulSoup 3* - it is no longer maintained. Instead upgrade:

```
pip install --upgrade beautifulsoup4
```

And make sure you import it as:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```